# Add json object into another json object using bash/jq

Tags: json, object, jq

I am trying to create a new file adding the object defined in country1.json into world.json. Essentially:

world.json

```
{
    "class": "world",
    "version": "1.1.0"
}
```

`+`

country1.json

```
{
    "class": "country",
    "country_1": {
        "class": "city",
        "name": "seattle"
    }
}
```

`=`

world_country1.json

```
{
    "class": "world",
    "version": "1.1.0",
    "country1": {
        "class": "country",
        "country_1": {
            "class": "city",
            "name": "seattle"
        }
    }
}
```

Using the filename for the objects in country1.json file. I would like to use bash/jq if possible.

Thanks for your help,
Best,
Romain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `input` to access the second file, and redirect using `>` into another file

```bash
jq '.country1 = input' world.json country1.json > world_country1.json
```

```json
{
  "class": "world",
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "country1": {
    "class": "country",
    "country_1": {
      "class": "city",
      "name": "seattle"
    }
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/0ytqxwApPKX)

---

If you want to utilize the file's name for the new field's name, use `input_filename` and cut off the last 5 characters (removing `.json`):

```bash
jq '. + (input | {(input_filename[:-5]): .})' world.json country1.json > world_country1.json
```